# Is there a way to "regularize" the Johansen cointegration test?

Tags: regularization, cointegration, eigenvalues

I'm using a Johansen cointegration test to check for cointegration among a large number of time series. I've found that while the eigenvectors look great in-sample, the cointegrating relationships often don't hold up out of sample. However, if I manually "regularize" the eigenvectors by setting the smaller weights to zero, then the OOS performance is much better.

Is there a more robust or principled way to perform this regularization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only work I know about "regularising" cointegration is the paper of Liao and Philips (2012) who use a Lasso shrinkage. But it is a very theoretical paper and their method is far from straightforward... good luck for the implementation!

- Liao, Philips (2012) Automated Estimation of Vector Error Correction Models, working paper, http://cowles.econ.yale.edu/P/cd/d18b/d1873.pdf